# Describe file upload for swagger-ui using serverless-aws-documentation

Tags: python, aws-serverless

I am using serverless-aws-documentation plugin to create a swagger documentation. Here how can provide a file as input for request body. should we add multipart/form-data to request model or what is he correct syntax?

```
documentation:
        summary: "Upload file"
        description: "Upload file"
        tags:
          - "file"
        requestBody:
          description: "Request body"
        requestHeaders:
          - name: "content-type"
            description: "application/json"
        requestModels:
          "application/json": "InputModel"
        methodResponses:
          - statusCode: "200"
            responseBody:
              description: "Response body"
            responseModels:
              "application/json": "OutputModel"
          - statusCode: "500"
            responseModels:
              "application/json": "ErrorMessage"
```

Comment: official documentation does not seem to have any explanation or example regarding this.https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-aws-documentation